# Se cambia el valor en todos los arrays C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, array, visual-studio, windows-forms

Hola quisiera su ayuda o ver si alguien sabe que esta pasando, al leer los datos de un archivo excel los guardo en un array y guardo dos mas para realizar otros procedimientos con ellos, pero al momento de modificar uno se modifican los otros dos, alguien sabe por que razon pasa esto, gracias.

```
                    var resultadoExcel = openExcel.Result(item);
                    var libro          = resultadoExcel.Item1;
                    var libro3         = resultadoExcel.Item1;
                    var filas          = resultadoExcel.Item2;
                    var columnas       = resultadoExcel.Item3;

                    var heuristica2 = libro;
                    var capacidad   = libro[2, 1];
                    var articulos   = libro[2,2];
                    resultBox.Text  += "Capacidad Máxima:" + Convert.ToString(capacidad);
                    resultBox.Text  += ("\r\n");


                    libro[0, 0] = 1; // Al hacer este cambio se modifica en todos
```

AL realizar el cambio en la variable libro tambien se ve afectado la variable libro3 y heuristica2.

Comment: Al cambiar el valor de `huelistica2` también se ve afectada la variable `libro` debido a que al hacer `var heuristica2 = libro;` no se crea la copia, sino hace referencia al mismo segmento de memoria. Para poder darte una solución, tendrás que editar la pregunta y mostrar los tipos de datos que utilizas en tus variables para poder determinar la mejor manera de poder encontrar una solución. O, en su caso, declarar: `var heuristica2 = resultadoExcel.Item1;` siendo que son los mismos datos que deseas manipular.

Comment: Creo que lo que tu querías/debías hacer es usar `str2 = String.Copy(str1)`. De esta forma tienes dos objetos string distintos. Al usar `Object.Equals(str1, str2))` te diría que son iguales *true*, mientras que `Object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2)` diría que son distintos *false*.